# Skmapview not cleared

Tags: android, routes, navigation, skmaps

I am using the Mapviewactivity to draw polylines, calculate routes, perform navigation. While doing one another task the polylines routes are shown in the map. How do i clear the map since I tried with

> SKRouteManager.getInstance().clearCurrentRoute();
>               SKRouteManager.getInstance().clearRouteAlternatives();

Comment: What if you keep a reference to the polylines objects , and call .remove() for every one of them :) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
navigationManager.stopNavigation();

I too had the same issue, The navigation UI elements stayed on even after the destination was reached, stopNavgation() removed the route and other UI realted stuff.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
SKRouteManager.getInstance().clearAllRoutesFromCache();
SKRouteManager.getInstance().clearCurrentRoute();
```

And then, Delete all custom POIs and Annotations and redraw them.

```
SKMapSurfaceViewObj.deleteAllAnnotationsAndCustomPOIs();
```